# create a master detail using CCK-drupal

Tags: drupal, cck

Is it possible to create a master detail form using Content Construction Kit in drupal? I would like to express a 1 to many relationship using CCK. For example I have a student and project, every student has many projects so every user for example has a table for projects. Is there any plugin for table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look at putting together something with the node-reference type which is part of CCK.](http://pras.net.np/blogs/guide-cck-nodereference)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use userreference module (D6, part of cck) to add a user field to your project content type, and views module to display user's projects.